# Codeigniter extends core class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to have class that checks login on all controllers that I specified.
Codeigniter version is 2.1.0 and I have php 5.3.10

Hier is how I would set it up:
I look at https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html
and I set it up like this:
in the /application/core/MY_Main.php

```
class MY_Main extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
}
```

In my controller I have welcome.php

```
?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends MY_Main {

    function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

So if I place login check in MY-Main it should get work, but I cant get it work anyone???

Comment: You should use codeigniter's session to store user data and check the session every time whether the user is login or not.

Comment: This should work, I do exactly the same thing in my ADMIN_Conroller.

Comment: hmm can you give example of you code...just like posted above...and do you have same version of CI

Comment: Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://miro.miroslavastrolog.com/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Answer (score 6):

I needed to add the following code to /application/config/config.php before I got the extenson of core classes working as described in the CI manual.

Code taken from here http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I added `&& strpos($class, 'MY_') !== 0` to the condition to avoid loading again `MY_Controller` in the same core folder. The `EXT` might not work nowadays, unless if you define it in _config\constants.php_ as `'.php'` (or simply replace it with this string).

Answer (score 2):

You logic is correct, that should work. It's exactly what I do on all my codeigniter sites. My code is a bit more complex as my login check is being called from a library (so I have to call `$CI =& get_instance();` and then `$CI` in place of `$this`) but something like below should work for you. `logged_in` is just a name given to an item of session data set when the user logs in.

```
class MY_Main extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $session_data = $this->session->all_userdata();

        if(!isset($session_data['logged_in']))
            redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

In regards to your comment above (http 500), not really sure what's going on there. The code you have pasted shouldnt be throwing errors like that so something else is probably going on. Try turning on codeigniters built in logging functionality.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html

Answer (score 1):

You should create a library class and put it inside your library folder and load it as auto_load or inside your controllers.
create functions inside your library for example:

```
  /**
  * 
  * @return boolean check if a user is logged in or not
  */
  function notLogin()
  {
       if (!$this->is_logged_in()){
           //echo "pelase <a href='login'><b>login</b></a> to continue ";
           redirect('home/login','refresh'); exit;
       }
       return true;
  }
```

and call it inside your controller constructor or any functions you want like this:

```
 class Main extends CI_Controller
 {
     private $POST = array();
     private $ci_form;

     function __construct()
     {
         parent::__construct();
         //check if user is logged in or not
         $this->m_auth->notLogin();
         $this->load->library('form_validation');
         $this->load->library('ajax_pagination');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It some time happens because of database connection.

Please check if your database :

1. has been selected by turning-on error reporting from your Cpanel error log.
2. user has been added to your database.